# I have a approximation (round) error issue in R

Tags: decimal, rounding, approximation

I have some simple error coming from approximation of decimal numbers in R. I guess it's due to the reserved bytes in memory or something like that...

I print those intermediate values for the variables while executing my R code, just to check where the error comes from:

```
prop_individues_stades[S] = 4.626294e-05
repart_pop_total = 1
pb1 = 0.9999537
pb2 = 1
frac = 4.626294e-05
```

The strange thing is that `frac` is calculated like this :

```
frac = repart_pop_total * (pb2 - pb1)
```

If i check directly in R, I obtain :

```
frac = 4.63e-05
```

I understand that it comes from round decimal places, but as I obtain `prop_individues_stades[S] = 4.626294e-05` and `frac = 4.626294e-05`, and my next step is `prop_individues_stades[S] - frac`, then I obtain zero and my program stops...

The ideal values without approximation errors suppose to be :

```
prop_individues_stades[S] = 4.6262936325314E-5
repart_pop_total = 1
pb1 = 0.99995373706367
pb2 = 1
frac = 4.6262936325259E-5
```

and then `prop_individues_stades[S] - frac = 5.5511151231258E-17` and the program will continue...

I tried with the function `round(frac, ...)` but it doesn't help.

Sometimes small values makes things important :) Thank's in advance for all your ideas/solutions/advices...